# Converting a JSON string to a Kafka Connect Struct

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am building a Kafka connector plugin and have input data in a JSON string and I would like to convert the JSON string into a "Struct" (used to create a SourceRecord) in a general fashion.  I can find a few transformers in Confluent Hub but none do the conversion in Java code.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a more effective way of doing this (if yes, is there a useful example in a github repo you can point me to?)
2. Is there a library (or github repo) somewhere that does the simple conversion... something like (ideally) the following:

```
:
import org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Schema;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.source.SourceRecord;
import org.json.JSONObject;

:
:
// the converter can probably taek as input either a JSON string or a JSONObject
Converter myConverter = new Converter();                                     // made-up class
Struct keyStruct = myConverter.toStruct(Schema keySchema, JSONObject keyIn); // made-up method
Struct valStruct = myConverter.toStruct(Schema valSchema, JSONObject valIn); // made-up method

// The keyStruct and valStruct are used to create a SourceRecord returned in a poll()
:
SourceRecord sr = new SourceRecord(
            sourcePartition, sourceOffset, topicName, partition,
            keySchema, keyStruct, valSchema, valStruct));
:
```

My Kafka Connect is configured (in Docker Compose) with the following parameters:

```
CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMAS_ENABLE: "true"
CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMAS_ENABLE: "true"
CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: "io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter"
CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: "io.confluent.connect.json.JsonSchemaConverter"
CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
```

Comment: 1) All "transforms" for the Connect API are Java code 2) Are you looking for [`asConnectSchema`](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/json/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/json/JsonConverter.java#L428) and `toConnectData`?

Comment: I think the "asConnectSchema" allows me to convert a JSON schema definition to a Schema, which is definitely very useful but different that what I am looking for. But now that I have a "Schema", is there a general way to load JSON data into the Schema to produce a "Struct"?  I would probably do this myself (there is a bit of complexity with deeply nested JSON but this is very doable), but I was hoping this may a common problem that someone has already addressed   :-)

Comment: The `SchemaAndValue` class is what you're looking for, but no, a Schema is just the "field names", not inclusive of the values for each field. For that, you need to reflect/parse your input to match each Schema fieldname

Comment: The "problem" you may run into is that handling "arbitrary" data isn't possible when you introduce schemas. You could look at using CloudEvents schema definition as far as "metadata" records you could add. For example, an HTTP response has a list of key-value headers and a response code that could be extracted, but the content-type isn't necessarily always JSON for any given HTTP server, so the `body` schema would need to be `bytes`/`string` unless you receive `Content-Type:application/json`, for example

Comment: Thus why the http source connector project has an [interface for a response parser](https://github.com/castorm/kafka-connect-http/blob/master/kafka-connect-http/src/main/java/com/github/castorm/kafka/connect/http/HttpSourceTask.java#L111)